# Keras fit_generator raises ValueError because multiple input not correct

Tags: python, numpy, keras

I have a working model that I can train regularly when using fit on a small dataset. However, due to the large total dataset size, I want to switch to a generator.

My model is a variational autoencoder that has 3 input layers. First I got the model working using the regular fit method. When I run the model as follows it works:

```
history = bvae.fit([data_class, data_regress, n_particles],
                        epochs = epochs,
                        verbose = 1,
                        batch_size = batch_size,
                        validation_split = 0.2,
                        callbacks = callback_list)
```

When I got this working I wanted to switch to a generator so that I could use more training samples. I tried to implement my generator as follows:

```
class DataGenerator(keras.utils.Sequence):
    'Generates data for Keras'
    def __init__(self, filename, sample_size, batch_size):
        self.filename = filename
        self.sample_size = sample_size
        self.batch_size = batch_size          # batch size
        self.channel = h5py.File(self.filename, 'r')
        self.list_class_arg = range(3, 67, 4)
        self.list_regress_arg = [x for x in range(1, 67) if x not in self.list_class_arg]

    def __len__(self):
        'Denotes the number of batches per epoch'
        return int(np.floor(self.sample_size / self.batch_size))

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        'Generate one batch of data'
        # selects data
        events = self.channel['SM'][index*self.batch_size:(index+1)*self.batch_size]
        # splits events into class and regress
        events_class = self.class_norm_to_int(events[:,self.list_class_arg])
        events_regress = events[:,self.list_regress_arg]
        # count number of particles in event
        n_particles = self.count_particles(events)

        print(type(events_class))
        print(type(events_regress))
        print(type(n_particles))

        return events_class, events_regress, n_particles

    def count_particles(self, data):
        'Counts the number of particles per events and returns that number in an array'
        n_particles = np.zeros(len(data), dtype='int32')
        for i in range(len(data)):
            for j in range(3,67,4):
                if data[i,j] != 0:
                    n_particles[i] += 1
                else:
                    break
        return n_particles

    def class_norm_to_int(self, data_class):
        'Transform the particle type to an interger number'
        class_shape = np.shape(data_class)
        data_class = np.ndarray.flatten(data_class)
        data_class = [(x*2.1659782700803696)+5.2390088017131005 if x!=0 else x for x in data_class]
        data_class = np.reshape(data_class, newshape=class_shape)
        return data_class
```

But then I get this error:

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
Epoch 1/1
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bvae_train_generator.py", line 96, in <module>
    callbacks = callback_list)
  File "/home/usr/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/usr/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1658, in fit_generator
    initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
  File "/home/usr/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training_generator.py", line 215, in fit_generator
    class_weight=class_weight)
  File "/home/usr/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1443, in train_on_batch
    class_weight=class_weight)
  File "/home/usr/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 757, in _standardize_user_data
    exception_prefix='input')
  File "/home/usr/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training_utils.py", line 105, in standardize_input_data
    str(len(data)) + ' arrays: ' + str(data)[:200] + '...')
ValueError: Error when checking model input: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 3 array(s), but instead got the following list of 1 arrays: [array([[5., 5., 6., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [5., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [5., 7., 7., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       ...,
       [5., 5., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [5., 5., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0....
```

It seems to think that I am only returning a list with one array, but as you can see in the result of the print statements, all three given variables are of the type numpy.ndarray

I've tried changing the return in __getitem__ to:

```
return [events_class, events_regress, n_particles]
```

or

```
return (events_class, events_regress, n_particles)
```

However, this doesn't seem to solve the problem. Any help is welcome!

**Edit:**

My model has the following form:

```
def initialize_bvae(beta, n_particles, latent, activation_func, extra_layer = False):

    'Network parameters'
    input_shape_class = (n_particles, )
    input_shape_regress = (n_particles*3 + 2, )
    hidden_layer_dim = 512
    latent_dim = n_particles*latent


    'Build encoder'
    inputs_class = Input(shape=input_shape_class, name='input_1') # Input for classification
    inputs_class_t0 = Lambda(lambda i: i)(inputs_class)
    inputs_class_t1 = Lambda(lambda x: K.one_hot(K.cast(x, 'int32'), 8))(inputs_class_t0) # Onehot encode classification input
    inputs_class_t2 = Reshape((n_particles*8,))(inputs_class_t1)

    inputs_regress = Input(shape=input_shape_regress, name='input_2') # Input for regression

    inputs = Concatenate()([inputs_class_t2, inputs_regress]) # Combine inputs

    x = Dense(hidden_layer_dim, activation=activation_func)(inputs)
    if extra_layer:
        x = Dense(int(hidden_layer_dim), activation=activation_func)(x)
        x = Dense(int(hidden_layer_dim/2), activation=activation_func)(x)

    x = Dense(int(hidden_layer_dim/2), activation=activation_func)(x)
    x = Dense(int(hidden_layer_dim/4), activation=activation_func)(x)

    'Latent space'
    z_mean = Dense(latent_dim, activation='linear', name='z_mean')(x)
    z_log_var = Dense(latent_dim, activation='linear', name='z_log_var')(x)
    z = Lambda(sampling, output_shape=(latent_dim,), name='z')([z_mean, z_log_var])

    encoder = Model([inputs_class, inputs_regress], [z_mean, z_log_var, z], name='encoder')

    'Build decoder'
    inputs_latent = Input(shape=(latent_dim,), name='z_sampling')
    inputs_particles = Input(shape=(1,), name='input_3') # Input for particles

    # Implement mask
    mask_fn = lambda n: K.concatenate((K.ones(shape=latent*n, dtype='float32'), K.zeros(shape=latent_dim-(latent*n), dtype='float32')))
    mask_layer = Lambda(lambda x: K.map_fn(mask_fn, K.cast(x, 'int32'), dtype='float32'))(inputs_particles)
    masked_latent = Lambda(lambda x: x[0]*x[1])([inputs_latent, mask_layer])

    x = Dense(int(hidden_layer_dim/4), activation=activation_func)(masked_latent)
    x = Dense(int(hidden_layer_dim/2), activation=activation_func)(x)
    if extra_layer:
        x = Dense(int(hidden_layer_dim/2), activation=activation_func)(x)
        x = Dense(int(hidden_layer_dim), activation=activation_func)(x)
    x = Dense(hidden_layer_dim, activation=activation_func)(x)

    outputs_class_t = Dense(n_particles*8, activation='elu')(x)
    outputs_class_t2 = Reshape((n_particles, 8))(outputs_class_t)
    outputs_class = Conv1D(8, 1, activation='softmax')(outputs_class_t2) # Classification output
    outputs_regress = Dense(n_particles*3+2, activation='linear')(x) #Regression output

    decoder = Model([inputs_latent, inputs_particles], [outputs_class, outputs_regress], name='decoder')

    'Build autoencoder'
    outputs = decoder([encoder([inputs_class, inputs_regress])[2], inputs_particles])
    bvae = Model([inputs_class, inputs_regress, inputs_particles], outputs, name='bvae')

    'Calculate loss'
    classification_loss = categorical_crossentropy(inputs_class_t1, outputs[0])
    regression_loss = mse(inputs_regress, outputs[1])
    reconstruction_loss = 20*K.mean(classification_loss) + K.mean(regression_loss)
    kl_loss = -0.5 * K.sum((1+z_log_var-K.square(z_mean)-K.exp(z_log_var)), axis=-1)
    bvae_loss = K.mean((1-beta) * reconstruction_loss + beta * kl_loss)
    bvae.add_loss(bvae_loss)

    bvae.compile(optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=1e-3, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999))
    return bvae, encoder, decoder
```

**Edit 2:**

Here is how I call the `fit_generator`:

```
history = bvae.fit_generator(load_data.DataGenerator(file_training, 1e6, 50000),
                        epochs = epochs,
                        verbose = 1,
                        workers=0,
                        validation_data = load_data.DataGenerator(file_validation, 1e5, 50000),
                        callbacks = callback_list)
```

Comment: you model definition does not match the input you are giving. can you post your model definition?

Comment: @ankeshpandey I added the model I am using

Comment: Can you also show how you call model.fit_generator() ?

Comment: @LucHendriks I added the fit_generator

Comment: Does this help? https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/2568 it seems to describe your issue

Answer (score 0):

you are defining multiple inputs in your model input_regress, input_class, input_latent and input_particles. All of these should be fed data while fitting the model whereas you are just returning (None, n) dimensional arrays from your DataGenerator. The error due to mismatching dimensions will go away if you feed all your inputs.